# Html Form : bad mime type for .zip files

Tags: html, firefox, file-upload, mime-types

**Situation**

I have the following form :

```
<form action="/url/to/action" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
        <li><label>File1 <input type="file" name="file1" /></label></li>
        <li><label>File2 <input type="file" name="file2" /></label></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Import"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Using Firefox :

- when I upload a `*.gz` file, it is sent with mime-type : `application/x-gzip`
- when I upload a `*.xml` file, it is sent with mime-type : `text/xml`

This is ok. However :

- when I upload a `*.zip` file, it is sent with mime-type : `text/html` instead of `application/zip`

(I checked the content of the POST request in the Firebug console.)

I'm pretty sure it worked not that long ago.

**Question**

Is this bug related to Firefox ? Has anybody else experienced it ?

I'm running FF 29.0 / Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have you had a look at the answers to this question to see if one could explain why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201945/how-is-mime-type-of-an-uploaded-file-determined-by-browser
Also, I am guessing that you know the mime type sent by the browser is un-reliable, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to add the mimetypes to a .htaccess like

```
AddType application/zip zip ZIP
```