# Why can't Firefox or Chrome determine a .json file's type?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

For an `<input type="file">` neither Firefox(34.0.5) nor Chrome(39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)) can determine a .json file's type. You can try it with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="file" id="file_input" name="files[]" multiple />

<script type='text/javascript' src='lib/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
$("#file_input").on('change', function(evt) {

  var files = evt.target.files; 
  //files is a FileList of File objects.
  var i;
  var len = files.length;

  for (i=0; i < len; ++i) {
    console.log(files[i]);
    console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
  }
})
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about telling us what the output was you received?

Comment: `""`  <------- file type for .json file

Comment: I get `application/json` in FF34

Comment: Chrome does fail though.

Comment: @sixfingeredman, what is in your .json file?  Mine looks like this: `{"planet": "world"}`

Comment: @sixfingeredman, I get the same result in Firefox and Chrome with `{}`, namely `file.type = ""`

Comment: I'm on Linux. The OS sees it as `text/plain`. Not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've circumvented the lousy browser support for the `.json` file type with the following code:

```
    #coffeescript:

    file_type = file.type

    if file_type is ''  #then possibly a .json file (is => uses ===)
      [..., file_ext] = file.name.split '.'   #If file.name is 'json', then file_ext will be 'json' as well.
      if file_ext is 'json'
        file_type = 'application/json'
```

...then I used `file_type` instead of `file.type`, e.g.

```
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': file_type, 
            ...
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to [How is mime type of an uploaded file determined by browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201945/how-is-mime-type-of-an-uploaded-file-determined-by-browser). It first checks the file extension name, so a *.json file will have `file.type` as `application/json`. If not found, it will enquiry the system for the file type, make sure your upload file is recognized as json file. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.type, it would be empty if unknown.

Comment: **According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.type, it would be empty if unknown** Yes, I am fully aware of that.  Better docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: *so a *.json file will have file.type as application/json*  The reason I posted my question is because a .json file in fact does not have a file.type equal to 'application/json'.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because the browser can't determine its MIME type through its [algorithm](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing-a-mime-type). [The specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#file) states that if the type cannot be determined, then an empty string must be returned. You should never reply on the `type` property since it will not be accurate.

Comment: How is it possible for a browser not to know the type of a .json file?  My file's got valid JSON in it, and its extension is .json.  I humbly suggest that Google might consider using a different algorithm.

Comment: @7stud - Why is it not possible? How does it know it is JSON inside but not only plain text?

Comment: there really is no standard json file format, like there is for gif, js, css, or html. it grew up as an interchange format, not a data archive format. what app does any computer come with designed to open json files?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, ...because the extension is .json?

Comment: @7stud - That's not how type works. There's more than just the "json" text. Though .json should really be a standard these days and Chrome should know it's application/json

Comment: By the way, that algorithm has nothing to do with determining a file's type.