# Why is MIME type different when using different PC but with same config?

Tags: php, excel, google-sheets, phpexcel, import-from-excel

I created a function to check the file extension of and imported Excel file. I have run same source on 2 different PCs.

**PC-1 Configuration:**

- Win 7 64bit
- XAMPP with PHP 7.0.x
- Browser Google Chrome
- Microsoft Office 2013 installed

**PC-2 Configuration:**

- Win 10 64bit
- XAMPP with PHP 7.1.x
- Browser Google Chrome
- Open Office installed. Not install MS Office

My Excel file was created by Google Spreadsheet and exported as an MS Office file with extension .xlsx.

In PC-1, when I debug the `$_FILES['file']['type'];` value I get the extension:

```
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

Yet on PC-2, I received:

```
'application/octet-stream'
```

My question is: Why with same source, same import file, just different environments, does the debug output show a different file extension? Is the cause installing MS Office?

Comment: It's server-side that reports the MIME type, therefore it is not related to what software installed in the client-side.

Comment: Thank Leigh for fixing my English mistakes. Raptor: So what is the cause of this situation.

Comment: I guess it's about PHP 7.1 vs 7.0's difference. Can you use [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.finfo-file.php) to verify the MIME type again?

Answer (score 1):

It's because Microsoft office isn't installed on PC 2.
So it Chrome doesn't know how to interpret.
Octet-stream is a last ditch attempt to interpret.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201945/how-is-mime-type-of-an-uploaded-file-determined-by-browser) goes into more detail and there's a way you can tweak registry to perhaps achieve same result.