# How to maintain a Vendor Specific Content-Type After send file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, content-type

When send a file that has a `Vendor Specific Content-Type` to an application **ASP.NET Core 1.0** your Content-Type is transformed into a different content type.

**Question:** How to keep the original Content-Type in upload/storage (Azure)/download. Should any changes be made to `Startup.cs` or`Web.config` (done manually, but does it work)?

**Content-Type Original:** `application/vnd.ms-pki.stl`

**Content-Type after send or autobind** (I did not identify when the conversion is done): `application/octet-stream`

Submission: the form is sent via Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: new FormData($("#")[0]),
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            // omitted
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // omitted
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // omitted
        }
   });
```

**Target Action:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PrintObjectCreateVM printObject)
    {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            await PrintObjectService.Insert(printObject);

            return Ok();
    }
```

**Action Model:**

```
public class PrintObjectCreateVM
{
    public IFormFile PrintObjectImage { get; set; }

    public IFormFile PrintObjectPrintFile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show the target action that the url is calling. you would need to set it on the response in the controller action.

Comment: @Nkosi added the action and model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser is unable to determine the content-type of the file to be uploaded *(e.g., inferred from the file extension or operating system typing information)* it defaults to `application/octet-stream`

For downloading, manually set the `Content-Type` when returning the file. If the framework cannot identify the content it defaults to `application/octet-stream` which any client should be able to handler.

For example

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DownloadController : Controller {
    //GET api/download/12345abc
    [HttpGet("{id}"]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string id) {
        var stream = await {{__get_stream_here__}}
        var response = File(stream, "application/vnd.ms-pki.stl"); // FileStreamResult
        return response;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Maybe work to download but on upload I need check if the content-type is accepted to the aplication.

Comment: @Ricardo I am still searching, but take a look at this for the time being. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303098/5233410 What seems to be happening is that it looks like the browser uploading the file can't identify the custom vendor mime type of the file.

Comment: @Ricardo found something that looks promising. Try setting the type on the input tag eg `<input type="file" name="PrintObjectImage" class="file-select" accept=".{vendor-file-extension}, application/vnd.ms-pki.stl">` reference [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) for more on how to set it

Comment: @Ricardo, I created a small project and tested it with a known and unknown file type. When using known type content-type was properly set by the browser and unknown's content-type was set to `application/octet-stream`. This would indicate that it is dependent on the client which would be outside of your control.

Comment: I understand, so I'll use this plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/ to validate the format by the browser before sending it to the server, Thank you!

Comment: @Ricardo no problem. glad to help. Happy coding.