# User uploads Excel sheet - filetype is application/octet-stream

Tags: excel, laravel, file-upload, base64

I have a web application running, laravel backend, where users upload Excel spreadsheets which then get stored, base64 encoded in a database. Mostly this works fine and the file is stored, looking like:

```
data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAA
```

However recently a user has had problems, her files get uploaded and stored as:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,UEsDBBQACAgIAGVKWk0AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

If I download her files, they appear as perfectly OK Excel sheets, and if I upload them again, even without opening them, they upload as XML spreadsheets.

Where do I start looking for the problem? At what stage does this encoding get determined? Is the the uploading OS, the uploading browser, or might Laravel be doing something behind the scenes? I am not a Laravel expert.

Comment: What recently changed? Is she using a different browser, or changed Excel versions, or is saving the file with a different file format? Maybe it used to .xls and she changed it to .xlsx.

Comment: [Here's an answer for how browser's determine the mime-type of the file being uploaded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303098/3585500)

Comment: I found out she was using a Chromebook and the spreadsheet was originally a Google Sheet. Must find a Chromebook to reproduce..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ourmandave pointed out, browsers do not have a 100% reliable way to determine a MIME type: 
[MIME types from browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303098/3585500)

In this case, the user downloaded a Google Sheet from Google Drive on a Chromebook (as .xlsx) and then uploaded the xls to me. The file was fine (and could be interpreted as an .xlsx file) but the MIME type at the file start on different Chromebooks could be:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64
```

or just

```
data:;octet-stream
```

Conclusion: don't place too much faith in the MIME type on file upload.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was not related to the browser. We tried to upload a Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx) file from several machines running on Windows. Same browser versions of **Chrome** (Version 83.0.4103.106), **Edge** (Version 83.0.478.54) and **Firefox** (77.0.1 (64-bit)) were used.

The difference appeared between the machines that had MS Office installed and those that didn't.

On the machines with MS office all browsers accepted the file with:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Browsers on the machines without MS Office accepted the file with:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue, as well. Took me a while to figure it out!